# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq' has no attribute 'prepare_attention'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, chatbot

I am trying to run my code and the code is throwing the error.
Error is mentioned below:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq' has no attribute 'prepare_attention'

I updated my tensorflow version to `1.0.0.` But the up-gradation did not solved my problem. I also searched in google regarding this error, but i did not got correct solution.

Here is the code part, please have a look.

**Getting the training and test predictions**

```
training_predictions, test_predictions = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(inputs, [-1]),
                                                       targets,
                                                       keep_prob,
                                                       batch_size,
                                                       sequence_length,
                                                       len(answerswords2int),
                                                       len(questionswords2int),
                                                       encoding_embedding_size,
                                                       decoding_embedding_size,
                                                       rnn_size,
                                                       num_layers,
                                                       questionswords2int)






C:\Users\Maniech\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py:1750: UserWarning: An interactive session is already active. This can cause out-of-memory errors in some cases. You must explicitly call `InteractiveSession.close()` to release resources held by the other session(s).
  warnings.warn('An interactive session is already active. This can '
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-aecd893a8ef5>", line 37, in <module>
    questionswords2int)

  File "C:/Users/Maniech/Desktop/Deep NLP AZ/chatbot.py", line 292, in seq2seq_model
    batch_size)

  File "C:/Users/Maniech/Desktop/Deep NLP AZ/chatbot.py", line 258, in decoder_rnn
    batch_size)

  File "C:/Users/Maniech/Desktop/Deep NLP AZ/chatbot.py", line 201, in decode_training_set
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq' has no attribute 'prepare_attention'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hey did you find answer to this?